# how to export MYSQL schema without data

Tags: mysql

is it possible to export MySQL database to a new server, and need the schema of the database without data except 2 tables

I have a MySQL database in my local system and I want to export this MySQL database to a new server, and need the schema of the database without data except 2 tables,

is it possible?

Comment: mysqldump with `--no-data`. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_no-data *except 2 tables* dump them separately.

Comment: I usually use a tool like [SQLYog Community](https://github.com/webyog/sqlyog-community/wiki/Downloads) where there's a function to copy a whole database or selected tables to a different server without data (Structure only).